# Checkbox state not updating in React hook functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing problem while updating check box state using React hooks,
By default check box is false.

Below code sample

```
function GPSPosition() {
   const [isEnable, setCheckBoxEnable] = useState(false)
   
   const enableStopSendingData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCheckBoxEnable(e.target.checked) 
        console.log(e.target.checked);// on check of CheckBox, here value is `true`

        console.log(isEnable); // true is not set to isEnable, value here is `false`
   }


   return (
                <div className="text-ellipsis">{GpsConstants.WIDGET_NAME}</div>
                    <Checkbox checked={isEnable} onChange={(checked) => enableStopSendingData(checked)} 
                  className="homepage-widget-checkbox text-ellipsis" >{HomepageConst.CHECKBOX_HEADER} 
                   </Checkbox>
                </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setCheckBoxEnable` is the asynchronous method so you can't get the updated value of `isEnable` immediately after `setCheckBoxEnable()`.

```
        setCheckBoxEnable(e.target.checked) 
        console.log(isEnable); // This will show old value of `isEnable`
```

You should use `useEffect` with adding `isEnable` dependency to check the updated state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(isEnable);
}, [isEnable]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems checkbox should work fine, but in case you need updated value after setting in state, you could use useEffect.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      // Here you will get latest value
    }, [stateVeriable]);
```

Comment: Yes i used useEffect, it worked Thank you

Answer (score 0):

delete th this line: `e.preventDefault();`

reference [Event/preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Even after removing this line it does not work, the above answer from William worked